# Creating a custom date field in Word (WWYY)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, datefield

I am trying to display WWYY in word using the excel formula TEXT(WEEKNUM(TODAY()),"00")&TEXT(TODAY(),"YY")

The purpose of the document is to display the week and year when the document was opened. Let's say the document was opened today. it should display 0823.

Basically, if I go to Insert -> Date  & Time , I would like to see a custom date field there as WWYY.

I tried creating the formula in excel and linking to word, but it's not working. I would like to implement this only in word for convenience.

Comment: If I add a leading `=` to the formula, it gives me the correct output, but I have a non-english version of excel and therefore had to modify some parts. Does your formula in your excel work as expected? If so, what exactly fails later?

Comment: The formula works in excel. I would like to use the formula in Word. I'm not sure if I must use Macros to make this work or is there a different way to handle this in Word.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have text as "WWYY" in your word document, the approach I mention would at least replace "WWYY" with the format you want.

You have to save the document as a Word Macro-Enabled Document (.docm). Open up Microsoft Visual Basic Editor using the shortcut `Alt+F11` or `Option+fn+F11` (macOS). Click on `ThisDocument` on the Project Toolbar on left. The Code editor for `ThisDocument` will open up. Now you can use similar code as below to replace Instances of `WWYY` with the value populated. For today's date `WWYY` will now be replaced with `0823`. I have also written another function that will revert the value(i.e. `0823`) with `WWYY` when the file closes. That way when the file is opened in a different time, the functionality would still work.

Beware! It will replace all the instances of `WWYY` or `0823`. So a better idea is to use a prefix to `WWYY`. In document you'd have `Prefix WWYY` and also corresponding prefix in both RevertWWYY and ReplaceWWYY functions. (`.Text = "Prefix WWYY"` in ReplaceWWYY and in RevertWWYY `.Text = "Prefix " + CStr(Forma...` and `.Replacement.Text = "Prefix WWYY"`).

```
Private Sub Document_Close()
    Call RevertWWYY
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Call ReplaceWWYY
End Sub
 
Sub ReplaceWWYY()
With Selection.Find
     .Forward = True
     .Text = "WWYY"
     .Replacement.Text = CStr(Format(DatePart("ww", Date, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays), "00")) + CStr(Right(Year(Date), 2))
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
     Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub
Sub RevertWWYY()
With Selection.Find
     .Forward = True
     .Text = CStr(Format(DatePart("ww", Date, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays), "00")) + CStr(Right(Year(Date), 2))
     .Replacement.Text = "WWYY"
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
     Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Word has no equivalent to Excel's WEEKDAY function. The desired result can be achieved via a field coded as:

```
{
{SET a{=INT((14-{DATE \@ M})/12)}}
{SET b{={DATE \@ YYYY}+4800-a}}
{SET c{={DATE \@ M}+12*a-3}}
{SET d{DATE \@ d}}
{SET JDEnd{=d+INT((153*c+2)/5)+365*b+INT(b/4)-INT(b/100)+INT(b/400)-32045}}

{SET a 1}
{SET b{={DATE \@ YYYY}+4800-a}}
{SET c 10}
{SET d 0}
{SET JDStart{=d+INT((153*c+2)/5)+365*b+INT(b/4)-INT(b/100)+INT(b/400)-32045}}

=INT((JDEnd+6-INT(JDStart/7)*7)/7) \# 00}{DATE \@ YY}
```

The above field code is based on the *Calculate the # Days Difference Between Two Dates* example in my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, available from:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required. The line breaks aren't required - they're just being used to make the code structure easier to see.

For a macro to convert the above field code representation into a working field code, see *Convert Text Representations of Fields to Working Fields* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

For anyone who may want to simplify the field code for getting JDStart, one could reduce:

```
{SET a 1}
{SET b{={DATE \@ YYYY}+4800-a}}
{SET c 10}
{SET d 0}
{SET JDStart{=d+INT((153*c+2)/5)+365*b+INT(b/4)-INT(b/100)+INT(b/400)-32045}}
```

to:

```
{SET b{={DATE \@ YYYY}+4799}}
{SET JDStart{=365*b+INT(b/4)-INT(b/100)+INT(b/400)-31739}}
```

Comment: @jonsson «I see you changed your post not long before I started typing these comments» I actually changed the field coding at least an hour before you posted your first comment...

Comment: I've further refined the field code. Although some of the calculations could be reduced to constants, I prefer to keep it the way it is so that the logic behind the process can be seen in its entirety.

Comment: Oops! - I didn't correct the first 'SET d' field - I left it as {SET d{={DATE \@ d}+1}}, but should have changed it to {SET d{DATE \@ d}}. Corrected.